# How to convert apache's slide shape element to SVG PATH?

Tags: java, apache, path, apache-poi, shapes

I used apache POI to convert (SVG path d="") to a shape object. 
The code is:

```
String d = "M100.000,100.000 L-0.000,100.000 L-0.000,-0.000 L100.000,-0.000 L100.000,100.000 Z";
PathParser parser = new PathParser();
AWTPathProducer pathProducer = new AWTPathProducer();
parser.setPathHandler(pathProducer);
parser.parse(d);
XSLFFreeformShape shape = this.slide.createFreeform();
shape.setPath(new Path2D.Double(pathProducer.getShape(),getTransform(translate, rotate, scale)));
```

Normal display after export as a PowerPoint.

Now, I am trying to do the import function, but I have a problem .

```
XSLFFreeformShape shape = (XSLFFreeformShape) xslfShape;
```

I got a shape object, but I can't turn it into path.

How can I get the "path" attributes "d" ?

How to convert it ?

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is something like that already. But you could [get PathIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html#getPathIterator-java.awt.geom.AffineTransform-) from the `Path2D.Double` and using that [PathIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html) to return the geometry of their boundary. Then converting that boundary geometry into a path string should be possible.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class CreatePPTXFreeformShape {

 static String getPathString(Path2D.Double path2D) {
  double[] coords = new double[6];
  StringBuilder pathStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for (PathIterator pathIterator = path2D.getPathIterator(new AffineTransform()); !pathIterator.isDone(); pathIterator.next()) {
   int type = pathIterator.currentSegment(coords);
   if (type == PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO) {
    pathStringBuilder.append("M");
    pathStringBuilder.append(coords[0] + "," + coords[1]);
    pathStringBuilder.append(" ");
   } else if (type == PathIterator.SEG_LINETO) {
    pathStringBuilder.append("L");
    pathStringBuilder.append(coords[0] + "," + coords[1]);
    pathStringBuilder.append(" ");
   } else if (type == PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO) {
    pathStringBuilder.append("Q");
    pathStringBuilder.append(coords[0] + "," + coords[1] + "," + coords[2] + "," + coords[3]);
    pathStringBuilder.append(" ");
   } else if (type == PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO) {
    pathStringBuilder.append("C");
    pathStringBuilder.append(coords[0] + "," + coords[1] + "," + coords[2]+ "," + coords[3] + "," + coords[4] + "," + coords[5]);
    pathStringBuilder.append(" ");
   } else if (type == PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE) {
    pathStringBuilder.append("Z");
    pathStringBuilder.append(" ");
   }
  }
  return pathStringBuilder.toString();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();
  XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();

  Path2D.Double path2D = null;

  XSLFFreeformShape shape1 = slide.createFreeform();

  path2D = new Path2D.Double();
  path2D.moveTo(100.000,100.000);
  path2D.lineTo(-0.000,100.000);
  path2D.lineTo(-0.000,-0.000);
  path2D.lineTo(100.000,-0.000);
  //path2D.lineTo(100.000,100.000);
  path2D.closePath();

  shape1.setPath(path2D);

  shape1.setLineWidth(1.0);
  shape1.setLineColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
  shape1.setAnchor(new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100));

  XSLFFreeformShape shape2 = slide.createFreeform();
  path2D = new Path2D.Double();
  path2D.moveTo(100.000,100.000);
  path2D.curveTo(60.000,0.000, 40.000,0.000, 0.000,100.000);
  path2D.closePath();

  shape2.setPath(path2D);

  shape2.setLineWidth(1.0);
  shape2.setLineColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
  shape2.setAnchor(new Rectangle(300, 100, 100, 100));

  XSLFFreeformShape shape3 = slide.createFreeform();
  path2D = new Path2D.Double();
  path2D.moveTo(100.000,100.000);
  path2D.quadTo(50.000,0.000, 0.000,100.000);
  path2D.closePath();

  shape3.setPath(path2D);

  shape3.setLineWidth(1.0);
  shape3.setLineColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
  shape3.setAnchor(new Rectangle(500, 100, 100, 100));

  String pathString = getPathString(shape1.getPath());
  System.out.println(pathString);

  pathString = getPathString(shape2.getPath());
  System.out.println(pathString);

  pathString = getPathString(shape3.getPath());
  System.out.println(pathString);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreatePPTXFreeformShape.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: My previous processing method was also stitching strings.But I use the length of the coordinate array to judge.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The XSLFAutoShape object and the XSLFConnectorShape object seems to only get the coordinates of the border. I looked at its xml structure and found that there is no data for the geometric boundaries. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @wei: Your first comment I do not understand. The question was how to get a `SVG` path string out of a `Path2D.Double` got from a `XSLFFreeformShape`. This is what my `getPathString` does. To your second comment: Only `XSLFFreeformShape` bases on path geometric. Other PowerPoint shapes have fixed shapes which are not based on path geometric.